# How to navigate a dict by list of keys?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, key, traversal

Starting with a nested dictionary like this:

```
my_dict = {"North America" : { "USA" : { "Virginia" : ["Norfolk","Richmond","Charlottesville"], "New York": ["Albany"]}, "Canada" : {"Saskatchewan": ["Saskatoon"], "New Brunswick":["Moncton","Saint John"]}}}

print(my_dict)
North America
    USA
        Virginia
            ['Norfolk', 'Richmond', 'Charlottesville']
        New York
            ['Albany']
    Canada
        Saskatchewan
            ['Saskatoon']
        New Brunswick
            ['Moncton', 'Saint John']
```

How can I take a list of strings like `[key1, key2]` and programmatically return the nested object `my_dict[key1][key2]` when I don't know how many keys there will be?  Examples:

```
keys = ['North America', 'USA']
print(my_dict.???)
    Virginia
        ['Norfolk', 'Richmond', 'Charlottesville']
    New York
        ['Albany']

keys = ['North America', 'Canada', 'Saskatchewan']
print(my_dict.???)
    ['Saskatoon']

keys = ['North America', 'Canada']
print(my_dict.???)
    Saskatchewan
        ['Saskatoon']
    New Brunswick
        ['Moncton', 'Saint John']
```

Assume the "path" to the keys exists, but don't assume anything about depth in the structure.

Comment: _Avoid answering questions in comments._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can throw `functools.reduce` onto it.

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>>
>>> my_dict = {"North America" : { "USA" : { "Virginia" : ["Norfolk","Richmond","Charlottesville"], "New York": ["Albany"]}, "Canada" : {"Saskatchewan": ["Saskatoon"], "New Brunswick":["Moncton","Saint John"]}}}
>>> keys = ['North America', 'Canada']
>>> reduce(dict.get, keys, my_dict)
>>> {'New Brunswick': ['Moncton', 'Saint John'], 'Saskatchewan': ['Saskatoon']}
```

... or write your own function.

```
def nest_get(dic, keys):
    result = dic
    for k in keys:
        result = result[k]
    return result
```

Demo:

```
>>> nest_get(my_dict, keys)
>>> {'New Brunswick': ['Moncton', 'Saint John'], 'Saskatchewan': ['Saskatoon']}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
from functools import reduce

my_dict = {"North America": {"USA": {"Virginia": ["Norfolk", "Richmond", "Charlottesville"], "New York": ["Albany"]},
                             "Canada": {"Saskatchewan": ["Saskatoon"], "New Brunswick": ["Moncton", "Saint John"]}}}

keys = ["North America", "USA", "Virginia"]

result = reduce(lambda x, y : x.get(y), [my_dict] + keys)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['Norfolk', 'Richmond', 'Charlottesville']
```